# IIS certificates. Relation certificate with web site

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate

I need to setup https connection for my web site.

For a development I will use test certificate what can be generated by special test certificates generation tool of certification center. 
To create a cretificate I need to fill a form and test certificate will be generated after it. Of course for real certificate everything is more complicated but I can work with test only now.

My question is that during test certificate generation there are several fileds like certificate name, organization name, organization e-mail, city etc.

*But how generated certificate will be connected with my domain?*

As far as I understand certificate has to have some 'links' to domain name to make user know that certificate he received is from my domain and not for something else.

For example I have 'mydomain.com'. And I think that 'mydomain.com' have to be included somewhere to certificate and when user receives data from my web site it can see that certificate is correct and have information about domain. *Do I understand something wrong?*

Why does test server certificate tool not have domain address field?

Comment: Which test certificate tool are you using?

Comment: It's Russian cryptoprovider company and I can generate test certificates. Problem is to understand how to fill filds and where domain is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the client verifies the host name (and therefore how the server certificate should be) is described in the [HTTPS specification (RFC 2818), section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) (and in [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125)).

In short, your host name should be in a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) extension of type DNS. If there is no DNS SAN, it should be in the CN (Common Name) RDN (Relative Distinguished Name) of your Subject DN.

The rest (organization, e-mail, ...) barely matters from this point of view: it will depend on the CA policy.

It's good to follow this specification, even for test certificates.

Comment: Do you mean that if there are no SAN in certificates subject I can specify CN for my domain like this
CN = mydomain.com or CN = 192.168.0.10:2022 in my case because domain is not created

Comment: Firstly, no port number, just the host or IP address. Secondly, according to the spec, if you want to use an IP address, you *must* use a SAN of type *IP address* (not DNS), although some clients will let you get away with using just the CN. `CN=www.mydomain.com` should work, yes, but it's preferable to use a SAN if you can.

Comment: Thanks. There are test not real certificates so now I need to make it at least work. As for IP do you mean that CN = 192.168.0.10 in certificate will not work?

Comment: Yes, I mean CN=192.168.0.10 will not work with all clients (e.g. Java clients will reject that, for example), but some clients will still accept that (although it's not allowed by the specification).

Comment: Thanks for help. This site can be accessed from internal network by IP 192.168.0.10 and from Internet by https://100.100.100.100:5000 (fake IP - I do not remember it now). Can I put both IP to a certificate? Because if I have one certificate for external network users at internal see certificate issue. Or can I install two certificates at IIS and it will select proper certificate depending on request - internal or external network?

Comment: If you want multiple addresses, you'll probably need multiple SANs on the same certificate. Make sure they're not DNS SANs, but IP SANs.

Comment: It seems that it's not so easy. I have to investigate it in detail. Thank for help with my question